# ActionScript 3.0: Serialization of functions?

Tags: actionscript-3

Since Function is just another type I was wondering. Is it possible to serialize functions in actionscript 3.0?

Comment: Could you please explain why you would want to do this? There might be a work-around to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With AS3, Adobe gave us enough power to create, modify and run ByteCode at run-time.
You can achieve a 'function serialization' using this *runtime bytecode* concept.

This can get pretty technical, but I recommend you to read about some libraries that should help you:

[Libspark's swfassist](http://www.libspark.org/wiki/yossy/swfassist)

[Hurlant's AS3Eval](http://eval.hurlant.com/)

I should also point that *AS3Eval* should be easier to understand -- *swfassist* have no english documentation, as far as I can tell.
With *AS3Eval* you can modify code as a string and execute it at real-time, just like the old *eval* method.

Of course you can go hardcore style and implement a complex system on bytecode reading/serializing, but using such libraries would make it pretty simple.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? I am interested in how can I get the AVM2 bytecode of one of my function into a string, and how can I create a function using a bytecode from a string?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to serialize not just the pointer to the function, but the actual function contents and then send them to a remote machine? I do not believe you can do that, you would have to use some type of remoting to do something like that.

Comment: Yes, I mean the actual function contents. Pack up the compiled AVM2 bytecode into a string, manipulate it runtime and de-serialize it into a new function.

Comment: errr yeah... don't think you can do that.